# fatal: Cannot switch branch to a non-commit 'Branch_A'

Tags: git

When I do `git switch Branch_A`

I get the error `fatal: Cannot switch branch to a non-commit 'Branch_A'`

for a given repository, on Ubuntu only. On Windows and Mac, the same command works ok, all things being equal.

Doing a `git switch` to other branches on the same repository works fine, so it seems like "something" is wrong with this specific branch.

Doing `sudo git switch Branch_A` gives:

```
fatal: unsafe repository ('xyz' is owned by someone else)
to add an exception for this directory, call:
    git config --global --add safe.directory /pathToRepository
```

Even after adding the safe directory as sudo, the same result. A `chmod 777` to all files and folders does not help either. Even a fresh clone does the same thing.

If I run `git branch -a`, `Branch_A` is indeed listed.

I do the identical `git clone` operation on all operating systems.

I'm being extra careful with case too, case does not seem to be the problem here.  Interestingly, trying to switch using different case permutations (branch_a) gives the same error as above, like git is trying, in contrast a knowingly wrong branch name gives `fatal: invalid reference: bad_branch`.

Doing `git for-each-ref --format=$'%(objectname)^{} %(objecttype)\t%(refname)'| git cat-file --batch-check=$'%(objectname) %(objecttype)\t%(rest)'` gives:

`08f0e890eda9cec780d73d71a2ffd19225fd1635 commit    commit  refs/heads/master 8882fd010c6d92eb5f586100888d90e6ea152acb commit commit  refs/remotes/origin/Branch_F 5f8e4d2c4fffa827d4b5978b91157b59ddf0464a commit commit  refs/remotes/origin/Branch_E c5a94160f9cd93fdab11e4ad484b8a1610d8acec commit commit  refs/remotes/origin/Branch_D 166d1b17353457b58f31b1e5b96bbde5dc194b3e commit commit  refs/remotes/origin/Branch_C d6db17a2d158d3869f50cd19c2721a102c399580 commit commit  refs/remotes/origin/Branch_B 08f0e890eda9cec780d73d71a2ffd19225fd1635 commit commit  refs/remotes/origin/HEAD 9d87e8538377bc39ac979ca32abe3c0fa91157c4 commit commit  refs/remotes/origin/Branch_A 08f0e890eda9cec780d73d71a2ffd19225fd1635 commit commit  refs/remotes/origin/master 80bb09b2a8f7c4dff83eeda7b424a426052f56c5 commit commit  refs/tags/dbi-12856`

How can I switch to this branch on my Ubuntu machine?

Comment: Is that just a typo, using `sudo` here?

Comment: We'll need more information anyway. Does `git branch -a` list `Branch_A`? If it's working on Mac and Windows but not on Ubuntu, are you cloning your repo in a different way between OS's?

Comment: @joanis: The "Windows and Mac work ok" suggests that perhaps there's a branch spelled `branch_a` or `braNCH_A` or some such, and case-folding is finding the branch name, or that there's a *tag* spelled `branch_a` (different case than in the command in question) and the tag is being found via case-folding before the branch is found. In any case a `git for-each-ref` would help establish what's going on.

Comment: Well, I have just seen the best argument ever for the unsafe-repo change.

Comment: @torek Wow, reading your answer, this is a truly bizarre situation to get into. I'm upvoting the question, because although it is not that well asked (I just tidied it up a bit, at least) I think this odd situation needs to stay documented on SO with your answer, and this Q&A pair adds value here.

Answer (score 2):

> When I do `git switch Branch_A` I get the error `fatal: Cannot switch branch to a non-commit 'Branch_A'`

I can reproduce this problem by creating a valid branch name containing an invalid hash ID, where the hash ID is that of a `tree` object instead of a `commit` object.  For instance:

```
$ git rev-parse refs/tags/v2.37.0^{tree} > .git/refs/heads/bogus
$ git switch bogus
fatal: Cannot switch branch to a non-commit 'bogus'
$ git update-ref -d refs/heads/bogus   # clean up
```

Note, however, that I had to bypass normal Git mechanisms entirely here.  Even `git update-ref` refused to write the tree hash ID:

```
$ git update-ref refs/heads/bogus refs/tags/v2.37.0^{tree}
fatal: update_ref failed for ref 'refs/heads/bogus': cannot update ref
 'refs/heads/bogus': trying to write non-commit object
 a4a2aa60ab45e767b52a26fc80a0a576aef2a010 to branch 'refs/heads/bogus'
```

How you got a bogus `Branch_A` name that refers to a tree here, I'm not entirely sure, but this does seem to do the trick as well:

```
$ git tag treetag refs/tags/v2.37.0^{tree}
$ git switch treetag
fatal: Cannot switch branch to a non-commit 'treetag'
```

so perhaps your name `Branch_A` is a *tag* name.  Try `git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name`.  For instance:

```
$ git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name treetag
refs/tags/treetag
$ git tag -d treetag
Deleted tag 'treetag' (was a4a2aa60ab)
```

If this is the problem, delete the incorrect name (as I did with `git tag -d` above) and then create the correct name with `git switch` or `git branch` appropriately.  You'll need to find the correct commit hash ID somehow.

(It seems to me that `git switch` and `git checkout` should take more note of cases when a simple name turns out to be a non-branch name, as in this case.  Had the name been been that of a commit, `git switch` would demand the `--detach` flag here.)

If you'll run `git for-each-ref` and attach its output (as a big code block) to your question, I think we'll know a lot more about what precisely is going on.

Comment: f-e-r on an annotated tag will show just `tag`, The full-fat diagnostic is `git for-each-ref --format=$'%(objectname)^{} %(objecttype)\t%(refname)'| git cat-file --batch-check=$'%(objectname) %(objecttype)\t%(rest)'`  I'm guessing OP tried `git switch junio-gpg-pub`.